# Ubuntu 18.04 goes into Grub Rescue after update

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04, grubrescue

Last night, when shutting down the laptop, there was a prompt to install updates and then poweroff so I did that.  Next thing I know, when I boot my laptop, I get the grub rescue prompt. Here's what I know so far:

```
grub rescue> set

cmdpath=(hd0,gpt1)/EFI/ubuntu

prefix=(hd0,gpt3)/boot/grub

root=hd0,gpt3
```

I tried to do:

```
linux /boot/grub/vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic root=/dev/sda3
```

and I get:

```
Unknown command `linux'.
```

I've also tried to:

```
insmod /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/linux.mod
```

but I have not had any luck loading linux.  I can't do normal.mod either, nor boot. I'm stuck here and need some help on how to boot so I can do grub-install.  There's no other OS on the laptop and my home directory is in a different partition, for what its worth.  Please help me recover my Ubuntu.

Comment: what is the output of `insmod /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/linux.mod`?

Comment: There is no output. It's as if it went through without problems. I still get Unknown command afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

My problem has been resolved.  I loaded a live USB session of Ubuntu 18.04 and installed the Boot Repair.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Using the Recommended repair option reinstalled grub with the shim.